# Boolean mask on timeseries with different frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm trying to mask some timeseries data with 6hours frequency with a boolean dataframe that is at daily frequency. The result should remain at 6hours frequency. The following function gives me what I want but it's superslow and I'm shure there are much better versions to do this. I'm an absolute beginner...

Thanks a lot for any help on how to do this better...

```
#create dataframes
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,10,2,5,4,7,5],'b': [0,10,100,20,50,40,70,50], 'date':
                                       [pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01 00:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01 06:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01 12:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01 18:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02 00:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02 06:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02 12:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02 18:00:00')]})    
df = df.set_index('date')

bool_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [True,False],'b': [False,True], 'date':
                                       [pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02')]})  
bool_df = bool_df.set_index('date')
```

```
def mask_result(mask, dataframe):
    pd.set_option('use_inf_as_na', True)
    df_result=dataframe[:0]
    ratio_resamp=dataframe.resample('d')
    
    for name, ratio in ratio_resamp:
        day=name.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        boolmask=mask[mask.index==day].values
        df_result=df_result.append(ratio/boolmask)
        
    return df_result

mask_result(bool_df,df)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you merge the original data w/the mask data you can use `np.where` to apply the mask.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,1,10,2,5,4,7,5],'b': [0,10,100,20,50,40,70,50], 'date':
                                       [pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01 00:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01 06:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01 12:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01 18:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02 00:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02 06:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02 12:00:00'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02 18:00:00')]}) 

bool_df = pd.DataFrame({'a_mask': [True,False],'b_mask': [False,True], 'date_mask':
                                       [pd.to_datetime('2017-04-01'),
                                        pd.to_datetime('2017-04-02')]})  

df = df.merge(bool_df, left_on=pd.to_datetime(df.date.dt.date), right_on='date_mask')
df['a'] = np.where(df['a_mask'], df['a'], np.nan)
df['b'] = np.where(df['b_mask'], df['b'], np.nan)

df[['date', 'a','b']]
```

Output

```
          date             a       b
0   2017-04-01 00:00:00  0.0     NaN
1   2017-04-01 06:00:00  1.0     NaN
2   2017-04-01 12:00:00 10.0     NaN
3   2017-04-01 18:00:00  2.0     NaN
4   2017-04-02 00:00:00  NaN    50.0
5   2017-04-02 06:00:00  NaN    40.0
6   2017-04-02 12:00:00  NaN    70.0
7   2017-04-02 18:00:00  NaN    50.0
```